# How do I install Secondlife?

Tags: 11.04, games

How the heck do I install the latest version of **Secondlife** for **natty?** I have it in archive manager and now I am stuck, I have tried tutorials and nothing helps.

I am new to ubuntu and need much help. If someone could tell me commands to run that would help I have secondlife for linux version `SecondLife-i686-2.7.4.235167` I have it downloaded now what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to unpack the packet you downloaded. You can do it with archive manager. You can also do it from command line - since [the linux packet available for download from Second Life](http://secondlife.com/support/downloads/) looks like a tar-bzip2 archive, the command to unpack it is:

`tar -xjvf SecondLife-i686-2.7.4.235167.tar.bz2`

That will create a directory where all the files are unpacked.

2) You **may** perform an installation by running the `install.sh` within the unpacked directory. But it seems that just running the application will do this automatically, so this isn't required.

3) You can run the application directly by running the binary file `secondlife` in the unpacked directory. To do this from command line, enter the directory and just run `./secondlife`.

Also note that in the `README-linux.txt` file of the package it says

> For in-world MOVIE and MUSIC PLAYBACK, you will need (32-bit) GStreamer 0.10
>   installed on your system.  This is optional - it is not required for general
>   client functionality.

Hope this helps!